# How can we automatically generate comments for methods written by us in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse, comments

How can the comments or comment-blocks related to the methods be added by us into our [RCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_client_platform) application as soon as a new method is added?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In the preferences: *Java* → *Code Style* → *Code Templates*

At the bottom there is a checkbox, *Automatically add comments for new methods and types*.

If you have an existing method, you can go to the (empty) line just before the method, type `/**` <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and the comment is generated.

Comment: You can also put your cursor on the method and use `ALT+SHIFT+J`

Comment: Thank you very much Arne and Paul Webster for your mind-blowing answers. We all newbiez are always grateful to you guyz for the guidances. Thank you Both again.